# Iteration sequence is bounded

Tags: calculus, continuity, fixed-point-theorems

Assume we have a continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, and there exists at least one point $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$ satisfies the sequence $\{a,f(a),f\circ f(a),\cdots\}$ is bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Can we prove that map $f$ has at least one fixed point?

I think we should use Brouwer fixed-point theorem, since the sequence is bounded we can find a closed ball cover the sequence. But how can i find such a closed ball $B$ satisfies $f(B)\subset B$? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: There are strictly increasing maps $\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ with a unique fixed point. There is no closed interval $I$ with $f(I)\subset I$ for this $f$. There are examples in higher dimensions too, so one cannot simply reduce this to Brouwer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$(x,y,z)\mapsto (y,-x,z+x^2+y^2-1) $$
and $a=(1,0,0)$.